# Not able to save json back in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension for Twitch and I'm facing a small issue which I cannot figure out how to solve. I must say my javascript knowledge is not the best (I am a C# developer) and this time not even google could help me (maybe because I don't know the correct search terms).

So to the problem. The goal of this extension is to notify you when a streamer changes games during live stream. I would like to notify the user only once per game changed. I have an array which contains objects, this object is a `class` with some properties, one of the properties is `game`. This array is then parsed into a json string to be saved in the browser `localstorage`. Below is the code i'm using to check what game is the streamer playing and trying to set the property `game` to that value. Then parsing the array back to json string and set the `localstorage`.

```
function checkPlaying() {
    var twitchUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.twitchUsers);

    if (twitchUsers.length > 0) {
        var f = (function () {

            var xhr = [];
            for (i = 0; i < twitchUsers.length; i++) {
                (function (i) {

                    if (twitchUsers[i].isOnline) {
                        xhr[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr[i].open('GET', REQUEST_BASE + REQUEST_CHANNELS + twitchUsers[i].id, true);
                        xhr[i].setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json')
                        xhr[i].setRequestHeader('Client-ID', CLIENT_ID)

                        xhr[i].onreadystatechange = function () {
                            if (xhr[i].readyState == 4 && xhr[i].status == 200) {
                                var response = JSON.parse(xhr[i].responseText);
                                var currentGame = response.game;

                                if (twitchUsers[i].game != currentGame) {
                                    twitchUsers[i].game = currentGame;

                                    if (twitchUsers[i].notify) {
                                        browser.notifications.create({
                                            "type": "basic",
                                            "iconUrl": twitchUsers[i].logo,
                                            "title": "TwitchWatcher",
                                            "message": twitchUsers[i].name + ' is currently playing ' + twitchUsers[i].game
                                          });
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        xhr[i].send();
                    }

                    localStorage.twitchUsers = JSON.stringify(twitchUsers);
                })(i);
            }
        })();
    }
}
```

The issue is that `localStorage.twitchUsers` never gets the new values, and this causes the extension to keep notifying the user with the same game.

I have tried to change the position of `localStorage.twitchUsers = JSON.stringify(twitchUsers);` to inside of the `for loop` and to the outside of the `f` variable, but I had no success.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Use `localStorage.setItem("twitchUsers", JSON.stringify(twitchUsers));` and `twitchUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("twitchUsers"));` - obviously do some error checking but that should help -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

Comment: @Archer thanks, it did the trick for Chrome but not Firefox. I guess there is a different way to save using firefox?!

Comment: You're saving to storage without waiting for the asynchronous XHR to complete.

Comment: @wOxxOm I did thought the same, in C# to wait for an asynchronous method I would use the async keyword, how do I do it in Javascript though?

Comment: You can find many examples, in short: Promises.

Comment: I will look into Promises. Thank you